# May URL scheme contain an underscore?

Tags: url, url-scheme

According to the spec for URL, can the scheme have an underscore? E.g., is web_view://example.com a valid URL?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**No.**

A valid [RFC 3986 URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-17) scheme must consist of *"a letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-")."*

```
    scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
```