# How to get the port number from the URL using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, port

This is the URL:

```
http:// localhost:8888/index.html.
```

How to get the port number from this URL using jQuery?

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Duplicate [javascript: get protocol,domain and port from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/javascript-get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is available in the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object:

```
location.port
```

Note that when no port is present in the URL, `location.port` will return an empty string.

If you need to get the port even when the implicit default port is used, try:

```
var port = location.port || (location.protocol === 'https:' ? '443' : '80');
```

This should suffice for pages served through `http` and `https` protocols.

Comment: Where's location.port mentioned on that MDN page?

Comment: @j08691 good point, I've replaced the link. `window.location` inherits it from the `URLUtils` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for it.

```
window.document.location.port
```