# How to correct find domain and port in javascript?

Tags: javascript

at first : I had problem to read image ina javascript like this:

```
var image = "/images/my_image.png"
```

so I try another way. But is this way of how to check the real path correct? Thank you for your comments.

```
var string = location.port;
var full_url = "";

if(string != ""){full_url = document.domain + ":" + string;}
else{full_url = document.domain;}

var image = "http://"+full_url+"/images/my_image.png"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I had problem to read image in a javascript like this."? Can you explain further? That should work..

Comment: "I had problem to read image in a javascript like this." -> I did mean that I had problem to load image with my first code ... in this way. (excuse me for my english gramma)

Comment: Can you show us how you're loading image?

Comment: `window.location.protocol = "http:"
    window.location.host = "stackoverflow.com"
    window.location.pathname = "/questions/28831940/how-to-correct-find-domain-and-port-in-javascript"`

Comment: It is for google map : https://jsfiddle.net/w73qtukh/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get protocol,domain and port from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url)