# Jquery datepicker conditional formatting

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker in different product pages in my WordPress site.

Each of the pages required different conditions of datepicker. Such as disable specific dates, holidays, etc.

e.g.

- if page 1
      then datepicker will show this specific dates only
- if page 2
      then datepicker will show antoher specific dates which is different from "page 1"
- if page 3
      then datepicker will show another specific dates which will show different from "page 1" and "page 2"

The site url:
http://www.mantisphotoexpeditions.in/expeditions/jimcorbett

You can see the datepicker in the "query" tab.

I'm also using ""contact form 7 datepicker"

Comment: You can use `window.location.href` to anlyze the url (`regex`, `split`,..) and then create a different `object` that will be passed to the `.datapicker() `function

Comment: Use different id or class for each input field linked with datepicker

Comment: @Mantis I'm not a wordpress developer, but speaking in general if you can only access to jquery you should retrieve the url in a "secure" way and retrieve the part you need, check this:[Retrieve url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url), then you have to do a `switch` or `if` statement to check the information and create a different object for each case with the datapicker option: `var optArr={opt1:value, opt2:value,...}` and finally pass it to `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({optArr});`