# How to fetch current domain or url with jquery in mvc website

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i need to get current domain name or url with jquery in my MVC website.

Here is my code:

```
 <script>
 // var ROOT = 'http://192.168.1.100/';
  var ROOT = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.button-search').click(function () {
window.location =ROOT + "Products/Index?DepartmentId=" +  $.trim($('#filter_name').val());                               
    });
});
```

My website url liks like this way:

```
 http://192.168.1.100/Home/Index

          OR
www.abc.com/Home/Index
```

I want to fetch  http://192.168.1.100/  or  www.abc.com/   with the help of jquery in my above code.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why do you think you need it? You can just use `window.location =' @Url.Action("Index", "Products") + '?DepartmentId=' + $.trim($('#filter_name').val());`

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url

Comment: @StephenMuecke  thanks i am trying this.

Answer (score 0):

to get the website current domain of the you tab use

```
window.location.host
```

and you can try this simple snippet code

```js
alert("full link :\n"+window.location+"\n website domain :\n"+window.location.host)
```