# How can I determine the URL of my application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angularjs and ui-router.  In my application I have an email feedback form and the email text will contain the URL of the application.  But when I run the application this could be:

```
localhost:1828 or the www.domain.name
```

Is there a way in my application that I could get the URL and the port so I could add this into the email?

Comment: Yes you can. However, this is more a back end than a front end feature - you don't want somebody to fake the URL if you do it from the client side. Thus - which backend are you using? Update the tag with that backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copied from: [Get protocol, domain, and port from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url)

```
var full = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can inject $location service to your controller/service. And use like this:

```
$location.port();
$location.host();
```

more info [in documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ui-router, you can use the $stateParams and $stateProvider to get the current url. See [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) for more information.

You can also use the [URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) feature to get the current url