# How to static ".com" content in HTML on a .org version of a website

Tags: javascript, html, url, dns, domain-name

I'm trying to manipulate the content of an HTML page.

**Scenario 1:**

When I change the domain name to end in `.com`, the URL in my content automatically change to `www.example.com`. This is the sample [**dotCOM**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpT9k.jpg)

**Scenario 2:**

Same thing to domain name ending in `.org`, the URL in my content automatically change to `www.example.org`. This is the sample [**dotORG**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoAPc.jpg)

**My expected output**

If I type the domain name ending in `.org` on the URL, I want the content `www.example.com` to be static `.com`. Like this [**Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idfTq.jpg).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sample Title</title>
    <link href="/css/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ol>
        <li>www.babyshark.com is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets 
        containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
        PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url

Comment: You have some weird problems... Anyway, can you show some code?

Comment: How is your content generated?

Comment: Will definitely visit the link @user1531038

Comment: Some robot is changing the .com/.org content depending on what I put on the URL.

Comment: @Damme Please edit your original question and place your code block there.

Comment: Done editing the question. Thanks

Comment: I hosted the website locally to IIS and it seems to not having any problem, but whenever the website is committed on the live server the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

below program should be help full to you

```
    function domain_after_dot(){
    var domainname = document.location.host.toString();
    var after_dot=domainname.slice(domainname.lastIndexOf("."),domainname.length);
     return after_dot;
    }
```

use document.getElementByid("id").innerHTML = domail_after_dot() which return specified domain of your domain name here id must be replace  which you attributes id

Comment: I am just thinking, is it possible fixing the problem without Javascript?

Comment: You can put statically .com or .org as per domain routing

Comment: I hosted the website locally to IIS and it seems to not having any problem, but whenever the website is committed on the live server the problem occurs.