# Full path to relative path URL without ending '/' Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I need to make
https://example.com/page/name/ -> /page/name
I wrote function like this:

```
rewriteUrl (url) {
    let chunks = url.split('/')
    chunks.splice(0, 3)
    chunks.unshift('')
    chunks = chunks.join('/')
    if (chunks.split('').pop() === '/') chunks = chunks.slice(0, -1)
    return chunks
  }
```

but you see it looks enigmatically. Can you refactor to something groovy?

Comment: Do `url = url.replace(/\/$/, '')` insead.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26434126/427146)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new URL(url).pathname.replace(/\/$/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**URL constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to get path name.

```js
let str = `https://example.com/page/name/` 
let url = new URL(str)

console.log(url.pathname)   

console.log(url.pathname.replace(/\/$/,''))  // if you want to replace last `/`
```