# Relative link to ColdFusion page with port number

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am trying to create javascript to change the location to a new page

```
window.location = 'report.cfm?action=new';
```

The thing is, in my development environment, I am using port 8080

How do I change my code so that it uses the right port?

Comment: ```window.location = window.origin +'report.cfm?action=new';```

Comment: Look at the answers to the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url