# Return only protocol and domain from full URI string

Tags: javascript

Given a full URI string I want to return only the protocol and domain name. For example:

```
sometodo("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/some/word1212/") 
// return: http://127.0.0.1 
    
sometodo("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/some/valorant_operator/") 
// return: http://127.0.0.1
```

How can I remove the third `/` and the following information from the string?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Also you should be able to find many answers to this if you just search a bit, since this has been answered many times before.

Comment: jQuery is a framework primarily for amending the DOM. To manipulate strings you just need plain old JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get protocol, domain, and port from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    sometodo("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/some/word1212/");
    sometodo("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/some/valorant_operator/");
    
    function sometodo(str) {        
        var output = str.match(/^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}/)[0];
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's going to be URLs then work with it as you would with an URL. No need to parse/regex/substring, just make an URL object and access its values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```
const url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/some/word1212/");
let result = `${url.protocol}//${url.host}`;
```