# How to get subdomain from url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a url like `http://abc.xyz.com`.
I just want `'http://abc'` part, But I am getting `'http://abc.xyz.com'`

I tried this:

```
windw.location.origin
```

Do I need to write some extra method to get the first part of url or is there something any `window` method which will do the same?

Comment: You have to extract it manually.

Comment: @Reporter so is there no any method like window or router which will extract only the subdomain part?

Comment: On client side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url

Answer (score 2):

You can split it by `.` and take the first element

```
window.location.origin.split('.')[0]
```

Example:

```js
console.log(window.location.origin);
console.log(window.location.origin.split('.')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://abc.xyz.com".split(".")[0]
// or
var url = "http://abc.xyz.com";
url.split(".")[0]
```

returns "http://abc"

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as that: `[subdomain] = 'https://abc.def.xyz'.split('.');`

```js
var url = 'https://abc.def.xyz';
[subdomain] = url.split('.');
console.log(subdomain);
```